# Codeigniter pass value through url simple php format

Tags: php, codeigniter, url

I am php developer. I just come in Codeigniter. I'm converting my php project in Codeigniter. So i want to send some values through url. I know the format of Codeigniter like this **example.com/index.php/controller/value**.

But I want to use simple php format like

```
http://example.com/index.php/controller?id=value
```

I want help to do this also i don't know to get this value in controller.

Comment: Is this form submit or `<a>` tag href ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### If `<form>`

So that your form should be like this

```
<form action="<?php echo base_url();?>index.php/controller/method" method="get">
```

And when you submit the data it will come through URL like this

```
CodeIgniter-3/index.php/controller/method?id=25&demail=bbb
```

So In controller

```
$id = $this->input->get('id'); # Output 25
$demail = $this->input->get('demail'); # Output bbb
```

---

### If `<a>`

```
<a href="<?php echo base_url();?>index.php/controller/method?id=25">clickkk</a>
```

So In controller

```
$id = $this->input->get('id'); # Output 25
```

Answer (score 0):

```
echo base_url("controller/test")."/".$id;

in your controller function 
function test($id='')
{

}
```

Comment: i don't want his format . i want controller?id=value

Comment: if your converting your php project into codeigniter then also convert the url too , why don't you just use the provided functions of codeigniter ?

Answer (score 0):

For a url like this format :

```
http://example.com/index.php/controller/method/?id=value
```

Just do this in the controller method

```
$this->input->get('your_variable', TRUE);
```

And dont forget the config.php file :

```
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'PATH_INFO';
$config['allow_get_array']      = TRUE;
$config['enable_query_strings'] = TRUE;
```